# Samsung TV remote control over UPnP

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, postman, samsung-smart-tv

I searched for Samsung Smart TVs on the network by sending an M-Search Message. Got the response of all the services advertised by the TV on the network.
Description Xml of one of the service is obtained at "http://192.168.0.1:7678/nservice/"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:sec="http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:device:dialreceiver:1</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>[TV] Samsung 7 Series (50)</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription>Samsung DTV RCR</modelDescription>
        <modelName>UA50RU7400RSMZ</modelName>
        <modelNumber>1.0</modelNumber>
        <modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
        <serialNumber>20090804RCR</serialNumber>
        <UDN>uuid:8b6394f7-19c7-423d-a229-017ddf94ba54</UDN>
        <sec:deviceID>NSNSC5ZTTO2RS</sec:deviceID>
        <sec:ProductCap>Resolution:1920X1080,Tizen,Y2017</sec:ProductCap>
        <serviceList>
            <service>
                <serviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1</serviceType>
                <serviceId>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:serviceId:dial</serviceId>
                <controlURL>/RCR/control/dial</controlURL>
                <eventSubURL>/RCR/event/dial</eventSubURL>
                <SCPDURL>dial.xml</SCPDURL>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
        <sec:Capabilities>
            <sec:Capability name="samsung:multiscreen:1" port="8001" location="/ms/1.0/"/>
        </sec:Capabilities>
    </device>
</root>
```

I am sending SOAP Request to the control URL.
I am getting a 404 from the server and a SOAP response as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
                    <errorCode>402</errorCode>
                    <errorDescription>Invalid Args</errorDescription>
                </UPnPError>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Note: Samsung Smart TV Model is RU Series 7.

Comment: ui4 datatype maybe means integer 4 so try 0013?

Comment: did you make any progress? I'm stuck with my RU7099. No request was successful so far, all Invalid Args.

Comment: No Commands are working. I have tried a different process to achieve the task.

Comment: I have the same problem, what are you make DLNA work with Samsung? The most fun, it good works with local video, but it is worth sending a request with a remote URL - have error invalid args